# "Error: cannot open display: :0.0" while starting Firefox remotely

Tags: firefox, ssh

On my ubuntu 14.04 remote server, when I try to start Mozilla Firefox 32.0 from terminal, it through error as follow:

```
$ firefox

(process:6397): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_slice_set_config: assertion 'sys_page_size == 0' failed
Error: cannot open display: :0.0
```

I have tried by changing `display` to 1, 10, 11, 99, however, no luck!

Banging my head from a week. Any help will be appreciable.

Comment: When you say _remote_ server, are you connected via ssh? Yre you forwarding X?

Comment: Yes, I have ssh to my server. Over there I am trying to start firefox in a same way as I am doing on my local machine i.e. from terminal type `firefox` and hit ENTER

Comment: @Jan Do I need to forward X? I am using `watir` & `headless` and `watir` opening firefox instance programmatically

Comment: Never heard of `watir` but you need to forward X.

Comment: how can I do this @Jan? And why I need it only on remote machine. Local machine works without it

Comment: Hi downvoter, glad to have your attention, however, I'm really interested to know the reason. Please comment so that I can improve.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

X11 forwarding needs to be enabled on both the client side and the server side.

On the client side, the `-X` (capital X) option to `ssh` enables X11 forwarding, and you can make this the default (for all connections or for a specific conection) with `ForwardX11` yes in `~/.ssh/config`.

On the server side, `X11Forwarding` yes must specified in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`. Note that the default is no forwarding (some distributions turn it on in their default `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`), and that the user cannot override this setting.

The `xauth` program must be installed on the server side. If there are any X11 programs there, it's very likely that `xauth` will be there. In the unlikely case `xauth` was installed in a nonstandard location, it can be called through `~/.ssh/rc` (on the server!).

Note that you do not need to set any environment variables on the server. `DISPLAY` and `XAUTHORITY` will automatically be set to their proper values. If you run ssh and `DISPLAY` is not set, it means ssh is not forwarding the X11 connection.

To confirm that ssh is forwarding X11, check for a line containing `Requesting X11 forwarding` in the `ssh -v -X` output. Note that the server won't reply either way.

[Source](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12755/how-to-forward-x-over-ssh-from-ubuntu-machine)